# Maven test finds but not executes tests

Tags: eclipse, maven, unit-testing, testing, junit

I have some test-classes under the folder src/test/java (some of these having name ending by *Test). Each class has some methods annotated with @Test
Running these tests with JUnit (on Eclipse, right click on the class, then run as, the JUnit Test) I have no problems. But I want to run these tests using mvn test.
The problem is that I obtain always this:
[image]

It seems that mvn finds the tests, but it doesn't execute them. Why? 
Furthermore, it seems that also classes having a name that doesn't end with *Test are considered by Maven. 
This is part of my pom.xml:
[image]

And this is part of my effective pom:
[image]

Comment: Try manually running individual test class by, 
"mvn -Dtest=YoutTestClassName test" to ensure whether your environment considers those classes as Unit Testcases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a very outdated version of JUnit.

In JUnit 3.x, tests did **not** use annotations; the **method names** had to start with `test*`.

In JUnit 4.x, test methods had to be annotated with `@Test`, which is what you apparently have.

In your pom, you need to upgrade JUnit:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```